# Why kohana 3 Encrypt class encode() method returns different string each time?

Tags: php, encryption, kohana, mcrypt, rijndael

I'm doing a `encode()` from the Encrypt class and each time it returns a different string for the same input string.
My `application/config/encrypt.php`:

```
return array(
    'default' => array(
        /**
         * The following options must be set:
         *
         * string   key     secret passphrase
         * integer  mode    encryption mode, one of MCRYPT_MODE_*
         * integer  cipher  encryption cipher, one of the Mcrpyt cipher constants
         */
        'cipher' => MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128,
        'key'    => 'df58e28f',
        'mode'   => MCRYPT_MODE_NOFB,
    ),
);
```

Use:

```
$str = Encrypt::instance()->encode('test');
```

`$str` has always a different value. Is that an error or it's supposed to work that way? Why?

Also I must add that I can always `decode()` that value and get the `test` string each time.

**UPDATE:** Here is a sample output: `0vahDa/2Qu3XQWObkjwLPoL73g==`

Thank you very much.

Comment: Probably includes the IV as well as the cipher text. What size is the output? ~32 bytes perhaps? Could use random padding as well, although not as likely. Might have included some output in your question.

Comment: @owlstead Thank you. Added sample output. It's 28 bytes.

Comment: Not really, that's base 64 encoding you've got there, which translates into D2F6A10DAFF642EDD741639B923C0B3E82FBDE hexadecimal. There must be a reason why that is 19 bytes, but I'll be buggered if I know. If you have an encode/decode in the same application, it is certainly possibly that your initialization vector is different for each encrypt/decrypt, or maybe it is encoded in those 3 extra bytes (NOFB seems to respect the bock size of the underlying cipher, being 16 bytes for AES).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is intentional behaviour.

IMHO this way the encryption is more secure. Most pseudo hackers would think different encrypted values mean different actual values.

The important thing is that you always get the same value upon decryption.

You have to be careful with that: when you want to use the same encrypted string twice you should store it separately, because encrypting again would not produce the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

The reason it's different each time is that when `encode()` is called a new random IV is used to encrypt the data. Here's the line that does it:

```
// Create a random initialization vector of the proper size for the current cipher
$iv = mcrypt_create_iv($this->_iv_size, Encrypt::$_rand);
```

It then ultimately returns a base 64 encoded string consisting of the encrypted data *and* IV.

```
// Use base64 encoding to convert to a string
return base64_encode($iv.$data);
```

It's intentional behaviour, and not a bad thing. As you noted, you always get the same unencrypted data back - so it's doing its job.